# Replicating input field content into div on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code that detects a change in an input field and repeats out the content into a div. When I refresh the page the content is remembered in the input field but isn't carried over to the div - it is just empty. How do I populate the div on page refresh in addition to the input changing?

```
$("#circuitsNum").on('change keydown paste input', function() {
  $('#circuit').text($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger one of the events so the event handler is called once on page load:

```
$("#circuitsNum").on('change keydown paste input', function() {
  $('#circuit').text(this.value);
}).change();
```

Comment: I pasted the above code into  $(document).ready(function() { - doesn't seem to work

Comment: @DanLee Well, the `change` method should trigger the handler. Pass `this.value || 'no value'` to the `.text` method and see what happens.

Comment: "no value" is output into the div on refresh wha I do as you suggested

Comment: @DanLee So the handler is called on page refresh and it should update the textContent property. So what is the problem?.

Comment: The original value isn't getting output into the div on page refresh, only 'no value' and when I edit the field I get a live update to in the div

Comment: @DanLee Do you mean you can see the previous input but `this.value` has no value? In which browser?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117092/discussion-between-dan-lee-and-vohuman).